# How do I stop overflow on my webpage when using AOS library

Tags: javascript, html, css, aos.js

I added AOS library on this project sushi007.netlify.app and now I have an overflow... How do I stop it the page from overflow?

I tried adding overflow hidden on all the sections. It worked but the layout shifted only when I zoom out my browser it looks okay

```
      <section class="newsletter section">
      <div class="newsletter__container container">
      <div
        class="newsletter__content grid"
        data-aos="zoom-in-right"
        data-aos-easing="linear"
        data-aos-duration="1000"
      >
        <img
          src="./assets/img/newsletter-sushi.png"
          alt="newsletter image"
          width="625"
          height="542"
          loading="lazy"
          class="newsletter__banner"
        />

        <div class="newsletter__data">
          <span class="section__subtitle">Newsletter</span>

          <h2 class="section__title">
            Subscribe For <br />
            Offer Updates
          </h2>

          <form action="" class="newsletter__form">
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter Email"
              class="newsletter__input"
            />

            <button class="button newsletter__button">
              Subscribe <i class="ri-send-plane-line"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <img
        src="./assets/img/spinach-leaf.png"
        alt="newsletter image"
        width="200"
        height="399"
        loading="lazy"
        class="newsletter__spinach"
      />
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Questions without proper debugging details will get closed.  Please add some code (not pictures of code) to your question and possibly an image to clarity what you mean by "overflow" here.  Feels like a working snippet with HTML and CSS (and any JS) would go a long way here to help us help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK, thanks. I just updated the question with what my HTML for the newsletter section looks like.